# magento connection host use beter perform 127.0.0.1 or localhost?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

magento connection host use beter perform 127.0.0.1 or localhost?

```
<connection>
  <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>
...
```

Comment: 127.0.0.1 shall be better

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382602/what-is-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-localhost

Answer (score 1):

127.0.0.1 is generally thought to resolve slightly faster.